# Transfering gddoc files from one Google Drive account to another - "No preview available"?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, flysystem-google-drive

I've tried to transfer some **.gddoc** files from my private Google Drive to my Nonprofit organization Google Drive.

I have my private .gddoc files synced to my hard-disk. I used my browser to log into the Nonprofit Google account and then I went to Drive and did `New->File Upload`, and uploaded locally synced gddoc files to the Nonprofit's Google Drive. So far so good, files are there.

However, when I try to open the gddoc files in the browser I get `No preview available". Why is this happening?

How to I upload private gddoc that I have localy synced to another Drive?

p.s.
The only difference I noticed is that files are listed without the extension on my private account, but uploaded files on the Nonprofit's drive do have an extension .gddoc clearly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

OK...
gddoc files are metadata only, they don't contain all the info.

The only way to go is Google Takeout:

- Export desired Google Drive folder using Google Takeout. This will (unfortunatelly) convert your gddoc files to docx.
- Wait for Takeout to finish, then get and unzip Takeout files
- Upload Takeout files to another Google Drive
- Open docx files one by one and "Save as google doc" to have them again in gddoc format.